# Best tools for AJAX

Tags: ajax

What are the best tools for AJAX development? I know of firebug for firefox, what other great tools are there for AJAX development?

Comment: "AJAX development" is pretty vague (and YSlow has little to do with Ajax), but if you need JavaScript development, then Firebug is the best tool around.

Comment: This is been asked dozens of time already. Please do a bit of searching for previous questions before asking this sort of thing.

Comment: I would agree with musicfreak that the question is a little vague.  However I would say that Visual Studio and IE 8 is pretty useful too, though I still use FireBug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jquery on the client side.  Makes it easy to request different data types, deal with different states of response, and hides away complexities.

gson on the server if you are using Java, converts Java objects to JSON output, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

You meant YSlow. Do you know that Google has recently realized firebug plug-in called "[Page Speed](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/)".

It is great, especially the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

DevExpress has a lot of out of the box AJAX stuff with their controls. They also have one cool control the ASPxCallback which allows you to implement your own that way. You can check it out [here](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Free/WebRegistration60/).

Microsoft also has AJAX framework for ASP.NET. Check it out [here](http://www.asp.net/ajax/).

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be doing .NET development I suggest using WCF services on the server-side.  You can create awesome little RESTful WCF services that will play nicely with jquery and Ajax.